# went or have been?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I'd like to know whether the past tense "went to" or the present perfect "have been to" should be used in the following. Do different dialects behave differently here?

> A: I **went** to Boston five times. / I **have been** to Boston five times.

> B: Wow! I'm so envious.

Comment: Given B's response, it's pretty obvious that the fact of the speaking having been to Boston five times is ***contextually relevant to time of utterance***. Since that's the main reason you might want to use Present Perfect, it's fine in your example context. But that doesn't mean it's "wrong" to use Simple Past - it's really just a stylistic choice here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between have been and went?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37978/what-is-the-difference-between-have-been-and-went) Also [“have been to” versus “went to”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51994/have-been-to-versus-went-to) and [Using have gone to / been to / been in](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115858/using-have-gone-to-been-to-been-in), among others.

Answer (score 3):

As often is the case, the problem with the examples are context. Without context things are often not meaningful. **Both cases mean travelled and are in the past.**

As a kid **I went to Boston five times** to visit my Aunt.

I am worn out! **I have been to Boston five times** this week.

**I went to**

went = go, go = travel

I travelled to Boston five times.

I **have been** = travel

I travelled to Boston five times

**[Been**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/been) verb UK  /biːn/ /bɪn/ US  /biːn/ /bɪn/

past participle of be; used to mean "**visited" or "travelled**",:

I've never been to Kenya, but I hope to visit it next year.
"Have you ever been there before?" - "Yes, I've been twice."

used as the past participle of "go" when the action referred to is finished:

She's been to the hairdresser's (= and now she has returned).
Do you need to go to the bathroom, or have you already been?

**Ref; CED**

*In relation to your comment on* **or the present perfect "have been to"**

We use the present perfect continuous to talk about a **finished activity in the recent past**. Using the present perfect continuous focuses on the activity.

We don’t give a specific time. Even though the activity is finished, we can see the result in the present:

I’ve just been clean**ing** the car. (The car is wet and clean.)

It’s been snow**ing**. (The ground is covered in snow.)

What have you been buy**ing**?

Comment: Is it wrong to say "I am worn out! I went to Boston five times this week"?

Comment: @Apollyon Not if you travelled there. However a better question would be is it wrong to say "As a kid I have been to Boston five times to visit my Aunt"

Comment: Why does this answer talk (at length) about present perfect continuous? There are no continuous forms at all in the question. It looks as if you are interpreting _been_ as introducing a continuous, but it doesn't  here (there's no _-ing_). In fact, the question relies on a special meaning of _been to_ (only the perfect, not other forms of _be_) meaning _visited and come back_.

Comment: @Colin Fine. Agreed I have tried to clarify my answer. I had tried to point out that both examples were of travelling in the past and then secondly the use of "present perfect continuous" I hope now this is more clear.