# "I've been to see the manager" -- meaning of "been to see"

Tags: grammar, idioms, vocabulary, present-perfect, questions

What does "been to see" in this excerpt from a listening test mean?

> Tutor: Hello Sam, come in and sit down ...
> Sam: Thanks.
> Tutor: You’re here to discuss your company-based IT project aren’t you?
> Sam: Yes ... I’ve **been to see** the Manager and he’s given me a lot of ideas about projects that the company would find useful. But I wanted to ask your opinion about them before I choose one.

Comment: "have been" means "went"; this comes up a lot here, such as [this question about "have been"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37978/what-is-the-difference-between-have-been-and-went). "to go to see" is a very common English structure too, with "go" a catenative verb followed by another verb to give the sense of travelling for the purpose of doing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence, the phrase "been to see" indicates that the speaker has visited or met with the manager. It implies a physical presence in the manager's office or location for the purpose of discussing something.
The use of "been to see" suggests an active engagement in a face-to-face meeting or discussion with the manager.

Answer (score 2):

It is an idiom meaning, "I have seen the manager," or, "I went to see the manager," or, "I saw the manager."

Comment: It implies that you went, probably to his office, for the purpose of talking to him.